# Magento 2 : How to get hreflang from address url?

Tags: magento2, url, hreflang, get

When i have the address: <link rel = "alternate" **hreflang = "de"** href = "..." />. 
I would like to take the hreflang value from this address, meaning "de".

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value with this code.

> var x = document.getElementById("myLinkID").hreflang;

Comment: I need to get it in php

Comment: Than how your current code for setting that value?

Comment: this value is set by the external module

Comment: yes, but using which code? then we get idea how to get this in php